# Changing title type in fancybox

Tags: jquery, fancybox, title

I'm putting together a photo website and am stuck editing FancyBox to change the title type to "over" so that it hovers over the image...

This is the jquery I have for the fancybox, currently:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        // use fancybox for hi-res images
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("a.image-link").fancybox();
            noIndent();
        });


        // remove image indentation in paragraphs
        function noIndent() {
            $("a.image-link").fancybox();
            $(".post.text p:has(img)").addClass("no-indent");
            $(".post.text p a:has(img)").addClass("no-indent");
        }

    </script>
```

Where do I add the title parameters?

Answer (score 0):

Provided you are using fancybox 2 you want to follow the directions [here](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs)
to pass an object when you call the fancybox function.

```
$("a.image-link").fancybox({
    "helpers": {
        "title": {
            "type": "over"
        }
    }
});
```